# python write list of float values out to excel

Tags: python, excel, list, floating-point

I have a list of float values:

```
LIDAR_RES = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

I want to write them out into an excel file. I am using xlwt to do this. My code below works fine with strings however states ''float' object is not iterable' when dealing with lists with just float values in it.

```
for i, l in enumerate(LIDAR_RES):
    for j, col in enumerate(l):
      worksheet.write(i+1, 3, l)
```

Comment: just drop the `for j, col in enumerate(l):` loop and it'll be fine. it "works" with strings because it iterates on the string letters. Probably not what you want, have you looked at the result with strings?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you just need one loop to acheive what you need as follows:

```
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
worksheet = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

LIDAR_RES = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

for row, value in enumerate(LIDAR_RES, start=1):
    worksheet.write(row, 3, value)

wb.save('output.xls')
```

Note, you can tell `enumerate()` to start with a given number, e.g. `1`. This way you don't need to keep adding `1` to each time in your loop.

[image]